File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 964, in start _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ()) RuntimeError: can't start new thread
When I am trying to rub localstack/localstack by
docker run --rm -it -p 4566:4566 -p 4510-4559:4510-4559 localstack/localstack

I am getting error
LocalStack version: 3.5.1.dev
LocalStack build date: 2024-06-25
LocalStack build git hash: ceb39832b

2024-07-04T20:11:45.735  WARN --- [  MainThread] localstack.dns.plugins     : Unable to start DNS: can't start new thread
ERROR: the LocalStack runtime exited unexpectedly: can't start new thread
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack-core/localstack/runtime/main.py", line 117, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack-core/localstack/runtime/main.py", line 113, in main
    main_v2()
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack-core/localstack/runtime/main.py", line 97, in main_v2
    runtime.run()
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack-core/localstack/runtime/runtime.py", line 56, in run
    self._on_starting()
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack-core/localstack/runtime/runtime.py", line 117, in _on_starting
    hooks.on_runtime_start.run()
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack-core/localstack/runtime/hooks.py", line 65, in run_in_order
    fn_plugin(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/plux/core/plugin.py", line 226, in __call__
    return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack-core/localstack/runtime/analytics.py", line 88, in _publish_config_as_analytics_event
    log.event("config", env_vars=env_vars, set_vars=present_env_vars)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack-core/localstack/utils/analytics/logger.py", line 39, in event
    self._log(event, payload=payload)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack-core/localstack/utils/analytics/logger.py", line 42, in _log
    self.handler.handle(Event(name=event, metadata=self._metadata(), payload=payload))
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack-core/localstack/utils/analytics/publisher.py", line 235, in handle
    self._start()
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack-core/localstack/utils/analytics/publisher.py", line 250, in _start
    start_worker_thread(self._do_start_retry)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack-core/localstack/utils/threads.py", line 111, in start_worker_thread
    return start_thread(method, *args, _shutdown_hook=False, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack-core/localstack/utils/threads.py", line 103, in start_thread
    thread.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 964, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread

**docker version            **
                                                                                                                       Client:
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.7
 Git commit:        74b1e89e8a
 Built:             Wed Jul 31 15:18:18 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.12
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       48a66213fe
  Built:            Mon Jun 22 15:49:35 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683

docker info
                                                                                                         Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 12
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 12
 Images: 8
 Server Version: 19.03.12
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.19.130-boot2docker
 Operating System: Boot2Docker 19.03.12 (TCL 10.1)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 1
 Total Memory: 985.4MiB
 Name: default
 ID: BUP7:ZGBZ:IIKP:IQ4F:ZPNX:EMDC:7Z3G:RWKC:Q52Q:RSAR:MCVG:CYQA
 Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
  provider=virtualbox
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine

System

Windows 10, 64
Docker Toolbox

I remove localstack/localstack and again install localstack/localstack on my Docker toolbox but result is the same
Then I reinstall OS, but the same error I am faceing

Please make sure to install at least docker version 20.10.10, we had a similar case raised for this in the past on github. GitHub Issue

I am using docker toolbox latest version is: v19.03.1 https://github.com/docker-archive/toolbox/releases, thank you for your comments
